# How to use Room library's @Ignore annotation with Kotlin compact constructor syntax?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm trying to use both the android Room library and Kotlin's compact syntax for specifying a constructor with default argument values. Something like this:

```
@Entity
class MyEntity(var myString:String = "non-trivial string") {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var myIndex:Int = 0
}
```

But I get this warning message:

> There are multiple good constructors and Room will pick the no-arg constructor. You can use the @Ignore annotation to eliminate unwanted constructors.

Where does the syntax allow Room's @Ignore annotation to be written with this compact Kotlin style of constructor?

I know that I can do something like this to eliminate that warning message, but it's more verbose. It also makes the constructor arg default value seem redundant/unhelpful:

```
@Entity
class MyEntity() {

    @Ignore
    constructor(myString:String = "non-trivial string") : this() {
        this.myString = myString
    }

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var myIndex:Int = 0

    var myString:String? = null
}
```

How can I declare a Room entity but still take advantage of Kotlin's brevity?

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add annotations to the primary constructor, the `constructor` keyword has to be added:

```
class MyEntity @Ignore constructor(var myString:String = "non-trivial string")
```

The [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors) states:

> If the primary constructor does not have any annotations or visibility modifiers, the `constructor` keyword can be omitted.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. I hadn't thought of that. But, believe it or not, when I do that, I see this new error: "Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type)." So, it seems that the @Ignore annotation is eliminating both the constructors or something.

Comment: This way no constructor can be used since the primary constructor is being ignored. I believe your suggestion from the question will do the trick then

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
@Entity
class MyEntity(
    var myString: String = "non-trivial string",

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var myIndex: Int = 0
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I still see the same warning from Room when I try that.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take this code:

```
class MyEntity(var myString: String = "default value")
```

If you decompile it, what you get is equivalent to the following piece of Java code (getter/setter omitted):

```
public final class MyEntity {
  @NotNull
  private String myString;

  // getters and setters omitted

  public MyEntity(@NotNull String myString) {
     Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(myString, "myString");
     super();
     this.myString = myString;
  }

  // $FF: synthetic method
  public MyEntity(String var1, int var2, DefaultConstructorMarker var3) {
     if ((var2 & 1) != 0) {
        var1 = "default value";
     }

     this(var1);
  }

  public MyEntity() {
     this((String)null, 1, (DefaultConstructorMarker)null);
  }
}
```

Hence, you get 2 constructors + 1 synthetic constructor. This is not crazy, since it must support both a constructor with a string argument and a constructor without any arguments (and remember that `MyEntity` can be instantiated from Java code, so Kotlin compiler must create both constructors).

If, instead, you write this code:

```
class MyEntity(myString: String?) {

    val myString: String

    init {
        if (myString == null) {
            this.myString = ""
        } else {
            this.myString = myString
        }
    }

}
```

The bytecode that you get is equivalent to the following Java code (getter/setter omitted):

```
public final class MyEntity {
  @NotNull
  private String myString;

  // getter and setter omitted

  public MyEntity(@Nullable String myString) {
     if (myString == null) {
        this.myString = "default value";
     } else {
        this.myString = myString;
     }

  }
}
```

With the second snippet of Kotlin code, you should be able to remove the warning and keep the `myString` property non-nullable, even though it is not exactly equivalent to the first snippet of Kotlin code since you always need to provide an argument in the constructor.

Comment: Thank you for the insights about the resulting Java code and the constructors Kotlin creates. When I run the suggested Kotlin code block (the one with the init block), Room complains about the lack of a primary key. When I then add a primary key field to the class, it does compile without the warning. Yay. OTOH, the class definition is no longer super brief. I'm beginning to wonder if the Room library's @Ignore annotation simply prohibits the kind of Kotlin brevity I'm looking for. Again, thank you.

Comment: @albertcbraun Yes, indeed it seems like Room is not "kotlin-ified" enough yet, so probably you need to trade conciseness for "warning-free"-ness. Good luck for your development :)